# excel-builder(.js) is giving an error after opening generated file

Tags: javascript, excel, excelbuilder.js

I'm generating an excel file with [excel-builder.js](https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js/tree/master) like this:

```
    require([
    './js/LibrariesForXLSX/excel-builder',
    './js/LibrariesForXLSX/Excel/Table'
], function(builder, Table) {
    var book = builder.createWorkbook();

    //creating worksheets

    var userDataList = book.createWorksheet({
        name: 'mysheet'
    });

    //creating tables
    var userTable = new Table();
    userTable.setReferenceRange([1, 1], [2, userData.length]);

    //adding data and tables to sheets        
    userDataList.setData(userData);
    userDataList.addTable(userTable);
    //adding worksheets to workbook 
    book.addWorksheet(userDataList);

    //adding tables to workbook
    boook.addTable(userTable);

    //creating download data;
    var workBook = builder.createFile(book);
    var rawExcelData = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64," + workBook;
    var blob = exp_getBlob(workBook, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    //downloading workbook
    saveAs(blob, 'export.xlsx');
});
}
```

where `userData` is a 2D javascript array like

```
['name', 'John Doe'
 'age', 23
]
```

`saveAs` is a function from `fileSaver.js`

Everything works fine and the file is also generated, but when i try to open the file with `Microsoft Excel 2016` i get an error like:

> We found a problem with some content in 'export.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

If i click yes everything is fine and the correct data shows up in the excel. **Can i somehow get rid of this error message?**